# How do I determine which revenue from the App Store belongs to which app?

Tags: app-store-connect

The iTunesConnect help says:

> Your financial reports are presented as groups of transactions,
>   displayed in distinct rows. Each row represents a unique combination
>   of an app, transaction type (product type identifier), price
>   (proceeds/customer Price), store, sale or return and promo (if
>   applicable).

But the downloaded report I have doesn't say which app sales are for. Is this because I only have sales for one app last month?

I'm wondering because I have a second app on the store now, and I have to pay royalties to people who helped with the games. So I need to know how much each app brings in each month.

Answer (score 1):

There are (free) services that do that for you. You can also generate nice looking reports for the people who helped you with the games:

- AppFigures (we've been using them for 4+ years): http://appfigures.com
- AppAnnie (not so much a fan personally): http://appannie.com
- LaunchKit (goes directly to Slack, but not real "overview"): http://launchkit.io/sales

Comment: I'm going to leave this open a bit longer as it might get some more answers, but this was helpful.